# How do i target input name with [ and . in it using jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have an input name that is `formComponentsMap['order'].firstName` how would i target that specific input in jQuery?

full input html

`<input name="formComponentsMap['order'].firstName" type="text" value="THOMAS" maxlength="20" class="form-control">`

Comment: read the documentation. https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ says how to do it right at the top of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could so something like this, using escape character "\\"

You can read more about escpaing special characters in jQuery selectors on [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```js
$(function() {
  console.log($("input[name='formComponentsMap[\\'order\\'].firstName']").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="formComponentsMap['order'].firstName" type="text" value="THOMAS" maxlength="20" class="form-control">
```

Comment: this worked perfectly! thankyou! is using ^ in this case because of the " that ryan mentioned below? again thanks everyone!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. ^ isn't required. but it still works because, it matches the attribute whose name starts with "formComponentsMap[\\'order\\'].firstName']".

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to do:

```
$("input[name=\"formComponentsMap['order'].firstName\"").val();
```

The trouble with that is that the second pair of `""`'s will escape the first, effectively cutting the selector in half and trying to target `input[name=\`.

Sreekanth's answer to escape special characters is probably best, but another solution would be to give the input an ID and do:

```
<input id="myInput"name="formComponentsMap['order'].firstName" type="text" value="THOMAS" maxlength="20" class="form-control">
```

and

```
 $("#myInput").val();
```

Comment: in this case changing the html wasnt an option :/